# Access with three conditional IF

Tags: database, ms-access

Good Morning. I'm trying to create an Access Query where it basically says that

If `[cc] =< 1.1`
then the `avgCc` is 1 and if `[cc]> 23` then avgCc is 23 and if `[cc] = <any other number>` the `avgCc` is that number.

How do i do that in a query in access?

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested IIF statement, just copy-paste it in your queries SQL:

```sql
IIF([cc]<1.1, 1, IIF([cc]>23, 23, [cc])) As AvgCC
```